# trouble with select title from a namedtuple list

Tags: python, list, namedtuple

I want to select the title of the book and make a new list in alphabetical order of that

```
Book = namedtuple('Book', 'author title genre year price instock')
             BSI = [Book('JK Rowling', 'Harry Potter', 'Fiction', 2009, 12.50, 10),
Book('Stephanie Meyer', 'Twilight', 'Fiction', 2007, 9.99, 1),
Book('Walter Isaacson', 'Steve Jobs', 'Technology', 2011, 35.00, 200),
Book('Albert Camus', 'The Stranger', 'Fiction', 1980, 15.99, 62),
Book('Shakespeare', 'Romeo and Juliet', 'Tragedy', 1597, 11.00, 13),
Book('Sake Jager', 'Language Teaching and Language Technology', 'Technology', 1998, 87.00, 27)]
```

for i in BSI:
   print(sorted(i.title))

Answer (score 0):

You use `namedtuple` fine.

Your use of `sorted` is incorrect.  You need to sort the *whole* collection by providing a `key` argument.

```
sorted(BSI,key=lambda x:x.title)
Out[39]: 
[Book(author='JK Rowling', title='Harry Potter', genre='Fiction', year=2009, price=12.5, instock=10),
 Book(author='Sake Jager', title='Language Teaching and Language Technology', genre='Technology', year=1998, price=87.0, instock=27),
 Book(author='Shakespeare', title='Romeo and Juliet', genre='Tragedy', year=1597, price=11.0, instock=13),
 Book(author='Walter Isaacson', title='Steve Jobs', genre='Technology', year=2011, price=35.0, instock=200),
 Book(author='Albert Camus', title='The Stranger', genre='Fiction', year=1980, price=15.99, instock=62),
 Book(author='Stephanie Meyer', title='Twilight', genre='Fiction', year=2007, price=9.99, instock=1)]
```